# How to make best fit line that is weighted according to precision of each data point

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, trendlines

I have got a set of experimental data called`xdata` and `ydata` that I want to approximate with a trend line. Traditionally, Libreoffice Calc calculates the optimal trend line using a method which gives each data point equal weighting when figuring out which trend line best fits the data points.

However, in the data set I'm using, some values of `xdata` are more "precise" than others, meaning the trend line ought to be closer to these points, and it's okay if the trend line is far from points that are "imprecise".

How can I calculate a best fit curve for my data that reflects this idea that more "precise" points should have greater **weighting** when determining the best fit curve?

I have included a screenshot and a more detailed explanation below to illustrate.

[image: ydata as a function of xdata]

In the graph above, the smaller the horizontal error bar on a point is, the more "precise" it is. I have set the size of the error bar to be proportional to the value of xdata.

One would hope to have a best fit line that is closer to the points on the **bottom left corner** of the graph, as they are the most "precise". I have considered forcing the trend line to have a 0 y-intercept, but am hoping to find another option.

Advice on performing this operation using other free software is also welcome.

Comment: The most practical way to do it with LO Calc or Excel is to use multiple regression with some measure of the precision (like 1/error) as the weight.  https://www.real-statistics.com/multiple-regression/weighted-linear-regression/weighted-regression-basics/ will give you a start.  But with a lot of data, considering the precision of each point is less important than fitting an appropriate type of curve.  Your data doesn't look linear, so fitting a more precise straight line will still be far less accurate than fitting the curve that represents whatever process is producing the data.  (cont'd)

Comment: And if you apply transforms to the data for the appropriate curve, you can still use multiple regression and weights to find the best fit.

Comment: Thank you for the link to that website! I understand how to do what I was trying to do.